# I can't pass lambda with reference capture

Tags: c++, function, c++11, lambda, function-pointers

Following code fails with this error

> E0413 no suitable conversion function from "lambda []float (int i)->float" to "float (*)(int i)" exists

```
int test;   
float (*f)(int i) = [&](int i) -> float {return test; };
```

How do I fix this? I need the Capture clause.

Comment: Then you can't use function pointers. Does `f` really have to be a pointer?

Comment: A lambda (with captures) is  some unspecified functor type, not the same as a function pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only do the above with capture-less lambdas.

See [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.closure#def:closure_type) *<sub>(sec 7)</sub>*

> The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression with **no
>   lambda-capture** whose constraints (if any) **are satisfied has a
>   conversion function to pointer to function** with C++ language linkage
>   having the same parameter and return types as the closure type's
>   function call operator.

Since [lambdas are not just ordinary functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and capturing it need to **preserve a state**, 
you can not find any simple or conventional solution to make them assign to function pointers.

---

To fix, you can use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) which will do it by type erasure:

```
#include <functional> // std::function

int test;
std::function<float(int)> f = [&](int i) -> float {return static_cast<float>(test); };
```

Answer (score 4):

A lambda (with captures) is not the same as a function pointer, and cannot be converted to one.

A capture-less lambda *can* be converted to a function pointer.

See [CPPReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), specifically the bit that begins:

> A generic captureless lambda has a user-defined conversion function template with the same invented template parameter list as the function-call operator template.