# Why aren't I allowed to capture in lambda function declared in class c++

Tags: c++, class, lambda

I am trying to write code to represent DFA's and approached the problem using lambda functions. I don't understand why I am not allowed to capture any variables in my lambda function to be used to compare with parameters. The error that occurs is there is no instance of constructor.

```
// Data structure for DFA
template <typename State>
class DFA {
    public:
        DFA(bool (*Qp)(State), State q0p,State (*Dp)(State, int),bool (*Fp)(State)):
         Q(Qp), q0(q0p), D(Dp), F(Fp) {};
        bool (*Q)(State);
        State q0;
        State (*D)(State, int);
        bool (*F)(State);
        int Char;
    
};

// Function accepts singleton sets
DFA<int> *acceptSingleton(int Char) {
    DFA<int> *singleton = new DFA<int>(
        [](int x) { return (x == 0) || (x == 1) || (x == 2);},
        0,
         [=](int qi, int c) {if(qi == 0 && Char == c) return  1; else if(Char != c) return 2; // error occurs when trying to capture
        else if (qi == 0 && Char != c) return 2;} ,
        [](int qi){return (qi == 1);});
        return singleton;
}
```

Comment: Your constructor takes pointers to free/`static` functions. capturing lambdas cannot be converted to such function pointers

Comment: please include the complete error message in the question. It does already tell you the "why"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't pass lambda with reference capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58055559/i-cant-pass-lambda-with-reference-capture)

Comment: Use `std::function<State(State, int)>` and `std::function<bool(State)>` instead of function pointers.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you will never hit the third condition in the capturing lambda, and there are cases where it won't return anything, leading to undefined behaviour.